# Do the concrete classes that implement an interface need to follow the interface definition exactly? (with no extra properties and methods)

Tags: c#, .net

Is it acceptable for a concrete class to follow the interface definition, but also vary slightly (like by adding an extra property or method)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Very much so. An interface says it implements at least the given set of behaviours but there is nothing to stop it doing more. Though of course you should always bear in mind that classes shouldn't do too much stuff.

A good example is that the `IComparable` interface (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx). This has a single method on it: `CompareTo`. Clearly an object with just this on would be pointless. Instead this interface does what it says on the tin and marks that you can compare objects of that type.

Comment: +1 I'd add `IClonable` as example. What's the point in calling clone if class doesn't have any method or properties but `Clone` :p

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: That is another excellent example. Now I'm wondering which would be more useless without any additional properties or methods. ;-)

Comment: But I read somewhere that if the class does more than what the interface defines, then maybe your using the wrong interface definition or not implementing the interface correctly.

Comment: @erotavlas: I think the "maybe" is the obvious keyword there. Interfaces have a lot of different ways they can be used. Sometimes you have an interface to allow common functionality between classes, sometimes they can be used purely as markers, sometimes they will just be an abstraction for another object to make testing and other things easier by coding against interfaces. If we are talking about interfaces in general though then there are definitely times when having more than what is on the interface makes sense. Some interfaces may well be designed to have nothing more exposed publicly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if it could not vary at all it would be the same as the original.

The interface defines expected pieces of the class so that common operations can occur.  As long as you have those met, you can do anything else you want.